# converted .mov file laggs

Tags: html5-video, quicktime

i have here a rendered .mov video file with the raw codec and 10 frames per second. The video shows a camera that rotates around a house. If I open this file with the Quicktime Player I can move around the house by dragging the mouse over the video. It's like an interactive video.

Now I want to embed this function in my website with javascript. The problem is that I want to use HTML5 videos, so I have to convert the .mov file into .avi or .mp4.

My Problem is now, if I do that the video laggs when I drag with the mouse over it. Even if I just play it it laggs. How can I convert this video so that I have the same quality as in the original?

Thanks in advance, 
conansc

Comment: What do you mean that it lags when you just play it? Does it not play smoothly? If so, you might have used too high a bit rate.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a GOP length of 1 (also known as using all I-frames). This makes it easier to play backwards. But you might need to just turn it into a series of still images, like JPEGs, and swap them to the screen as needed. Video formats are meant to be played forwards, at normal speed.